# Chi-square test - not able to match types

Tags: haskell, statistics, chi-squared

I am trying to do chi-square test using [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.0.0/docs/Statistics-Test-ChiSquared.html) statistics package function. I have following contingency table:

```
       A   B
True:  12  8
False: 16  9
```

I used following code:

```
import Data.Vector
import Statistics.Test.ChiSquared
sample = fromList [(12, 8), (16, 9)]
main = print(chi2test(sample))
```

However, it gives following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( rnchisq.hs, rnchisq.o )

rnchisq.hs:9:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                  with actual type ‘Vector (Integer, Integer)’
    • In the first argument of ‘chi2test’, namely ‘(sample)’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(chi2test (sample))’
      In the expression: print (chi2test (sample))
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Edit: As suggested in the answer by @JosephSible I also tried:

```
main = print(chi2test(1, sample))
```

(1 being degree of freedom)

But here I get error:

```
rnchisq.hs:7:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                  with actual type ‘(Integer, Vector (Integer, Integer))’
    • In the first argument of ‘chi2test’, namely ‘(1, sample)’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(chi2test (1, sample))’
      In the expression: print (chi2test (1, sample))
```

Following compiled and ran:

```
main = print $ chi2test 1 sample
```

However, the output is

```
Nothing
```

I expected some value. It remains `Nothing` even if I drastically change numbers in `sample`. Why am I getting `Nothing`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `chi2test` function performs a general chi-square goodness-of-fit test, not a chi-square test on a 2x2 contingency table.  It expects a set of pairs representing the "observed" actual counts and the "expected" theoretical mean counts under the null hypothesis, rather than just the counts from the table.

In other words, you need to work through a fair bit of statistical theory to use this function to analyse a 2x2 table, but here's a function that appears to work:

```
import Data.Vector as V
import Statistics.Test.ChiSquared

sample = ((12, 8), (16, 9))
main = print $ chi2table sample

chi2table ((a,b), (c,d))
  = chi2test 2 $ V.fromList $ Prelude.zip [a,b,c,d] [ea,eb,ec,ed]
  where n = a + b + c + d

        ea = expected (a+b) (a+c)
        eb = expected (a+b) (b+d)
        ec = expected (c+d) (a+c)
        ed = expected (c+d) (b+d)

        expected rowtot coltot = (rowtot * coltot) `fdiv` n

        fdiv x y = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral y
```

This gives output:

```
> main
Just (Test {testSignificance = mkPValue 0.7833089019485086, 
testStatistics = 7.56302521008404e-2, testDistribution = chiSquared 2})
```

*Update:*  With respect to the degrees of freedom, the test itself is calculated using a chi-square with 1 degree of freedom (basically (R-1)*(C-1) for R and C the number of rows and columns of the table).  The reason we have to specify 2 here is that the 2 represents the number of degrees of freedom "lost" or "constrained" in addition to the total count.  We start with 4 degrees of freedom total, we lose one for the total count across all cells, and we are constrained to lose two more to get down to the 1 degree of freedom for the test.

Anyway, this will match the output of statistical software only if you turn off continuity correction.  For example, in R:

```
> chisq.test(rbind(c(12,8),c(16,9)), correct=FALSE)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  rbind(c(12, 8), c(16, 9))
X-squared = 0.07563, df = 1, p-value = 0.7833

>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Do you think Haskell is good for scientific computing? Any advantages over Python?

Comment: I don't do much scientific computing in Haskell myself.  You may be interested in the [Data science](https://github.com/Gabriel439/post-rfc/blob/master/sotu.md#data-science) and [Numerical programming](https://github.com/Gabriel439/post-rfc/blob/master/sotu.md#numerical-programming) entries in Gabriel Gonzales' "State of the Haskell Ecosystem".  Also, Google for "scientific computing in Haskell" and read some of the resulting blog hits.

Answer (score 2):

`chi2test` takes two arguments, and you're only passing it one. Instead of calling `chi2test sample`, call `chi2test df sample`, where `df` is the number of additional degrees of freedom.

Comment: It does not work properly. Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: That's not how parameters are passed to functions in Haskell. Try writing _exactly_ what @JosephSible suggested.